# AS3 - How to swap display objects without interference with GUI?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using a auto display code to swap my children whenever the y value of the player and an object changes. So when player goes behind an object, the object goes on top the player and player goes below. And vice versa.

However I have GUI's such as crosshairs, and buttons, health bar on screen that should always be on top of the objects on stage. So for example, if the player is showing above an object, and I move my crosshair, the y value of the crosshair would change and then the interfere with the player and object, then the player would somehow show behind the object when it's not supposed to.

```
public class DepthSortSpace extends MovieClip {

 public function DepthSortSpace() {
 super();
 this.addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, this.addedToStage, false, 0, true );
 }

 private function addedToStage( e:Event ) {
 this.stage.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.enterFrame, false, 0, true );
}

private function sortDisplayList():void {
  var len:uint = numChildren;
  var i,j;
 for( i=0; i < len-1; i++ )
    for (j=i+1; j < len; j++)
      if ( getChildAt(i).y > getChildAt(j).y ) this.swapChildrenAt( i, j );
}  

private function enterFrame(e:Event) {
//always put crosshair on top
swapChildren(crosshair, getChildAt(numChildren - 1));
this.sortDisplayList();
  }
 }
}
```

Please tell me how to make it so GUI's and crosshairs get ignored and always stay on top of everything else, and only player and objects interact and swap when y values change.

I tried Aaron's method 1 answer.

```
private function sortDisplayList(): void
    {
        var alwaysOnTop:Array = new Array();
        alwaysOnTop = [crosshair];//this should always stay on top but then flickers with the player.
        var len: uint = numChildren;
        var i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
            for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
                if (getChildAt(i).y > getChildAt(j).y || alwaysOnTop.indexOf(getChildAt(i)) > -1 ) swapChildrenAt(i, j);
    }
```

Comment: stop putting all your object in the same display list, create a few Sprite and use them as layers to separate things.

Comment: That was a bad example. I've edited my answer with a better, completely re-written sorting method that preserves `alwaysOnTop` correctly. That said, I still recommend you just go with using container layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Adjust your sorting logic to always put certain objects on top. For example:

   ```
   private var alwaysOnTop:Array = [crosshair, player, gui];

   private function sortDisplayList(): void {
       var sortableChildren:Array = [];
       for(var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++){
           var child:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);
           if(alwaysOnTop.indexOf(child) == -1)
               sortableChildren.push(child);
       }
       sortableChildren.sortOn("y", Array.NUMERIC);
       for(i = 0; i < sortableChildren.length; i++){
           setChildIndex(sortableChildren[i], i);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Put all your sorted objects in a container, and your "always on top" objects outside the container. (This is the method I would prefer.) Just use your existing sort logic against various containers, and layer the containers however you want.

Comment: Method 2 is spot on.  It drastically simplifies the issues surrounding z-index with display objects.

Comment: I actually cannot use method 2, due to issues with parents. But I tried method 1, I still get the same issue, I posted my code above.

Comment: I think it has to ignore the crosshair and only check display on the player and objects.

Comment: What "issues with parents"? I'm sure there's a way to use containers as layers.

Comment: Looking at your existing sorting logic more closely I realized my example wasn't right, sorry about that. I would recommend you use `setChildIndex` instead of `swapChildAt`, then objects will easily "float" to the top without being swapped. Actually, I would *really* recommend you use the second approach and just put your objects in layers.

Comment: Well, I do suppose it would work. But then I would need to call parent.parent, and sometimes that causes more complexity.